# Mathematica Subgraph "Neat Example" not working properly in Mathematica 12

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

I have tried running the example given in the neat examples section of 'Subgraph' function in Mathematica 12.0 (windows 10) and the example does not run properly for any number of tries.

The same example however works fine in 11.3. is anyone else observing this problem? Is there a problem with the NeighborhoodGraph function on which the example depends on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sg = Subgraph[g,
 Complement[VertexList[g],
   VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, RandomSample[VertexList[g], 25], 1]]]];
```

The issue seems to be that `Subgraph` inherits the `GraphLayout` option value from the parent graph:

```
PropertyValue[sg, GraphLayout]
```

> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {25, 50}}

and, somehow, the vertex layout defaults to something weird when the number of vertices do not match the length of the coordinate list produced by the layout procedure.

So, you can

1. add the option `GraphLayout -> Automatic` (or use your desired setting):

```
SetProperty[sg, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]
```

[image]

2. remove the `GraphLayout` property from `g`:

```
Subgraph[RemoveProperty[g, GraphLayout],
  Complement[VertexList[g],
    VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, RandomSample[VertexList[g], 25], 1]]]]
```

[image]

3. use the option `VertexCoordinates` to retain vertex coordinates in `g`:

```
Subgraph[g,
 Complement[VertexList[g],
  VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, RandomSample[VertexList[g], 25], 1]]], 
 VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexCoordinates]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh thanks. so they made changes to how the graphs are displayed !

Comment: @Ali, it seem so. The issue arises when the automatic layout of the original graph has parameters that depend on the vertex count. Other examples where the same issue arises  are  `CompleteGraph[{3,5,7}]`, `KnightTourGraph[5, 5]`.

Answer (score 2):

How about filing a bug with Wolfram Research?  It only takes a few minutes.  In a notebook, click Help, Give feedback..., fill out the rest of the form (most is completed for you), and then click "Submit."  You don't need a service contract to file a bug, and there is no guarantee the Wolfram will see this Stack Exchange entry.